# Interactively change axis scale (linear/log) in Plotly image using R

Tags: r, plotly, scale, r-plotly

**Goal:** To create interactive dropdown/buttons to update the axes' scale for a Plotly figure from R.

**Issue:** There is a lot of documentation on creating [buttons](https://plot.ly/r/custom-buttons/) and [log plots](https://plot.ly/r/log-plot/) using `layout` and `updatemenus`; however, it was difficult to find one that described how a button could be added specifically for changing the scale of the axes. Some posts on stackoverflow provided solutions for doing this in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872300/how-to-enable-and-disable-the-logarithmic-scale-as-a-viewer-in-plotly/54873451) but I struggled to find an equivalent one for R. I have provided a solution/example here based upon the python solution.

**Starting Point:** With a small sample data-set, I want to create a graphic that can have the scale change from linear to log and have different traces on the plots. I have provided my own solution, but if anyone else has a more creative solution feel free to add!

```r
data <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), 
                   y = c(1000, 10000, 100000),
                   y2 = c(5000, 10000, 90000))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution based upon the one in python from the provided [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872300/how-to-enable-and-disable-the-logarithmic-scale-as-a-viewer-in-plotly/54873451); it was a bit tricky to know how deep to nest all of the `list`s. If you are not adding visibility to the traces, you can replace it with reference to the dataset.

```r
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

# Fake data
data <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), 
                   y = c(1000, 10000, 100000),
                   y2 = c(5000, 10000, 90000))

# Initial plot with two traces, one off
fig <- plot_ly(data) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = 'trace1') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~y2, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = 'trace2', visible = F)

# Update plot using updatemenus, keep linear as first active, with first trace; second trace for log
fig <- fig %>% layout(title = 'myplot',
                      updatemenus = list(list(
                        active = 0,
                        buttons= list(
                          list(label = 'linear',
                               method = 'update',
                               args = list(list(visible = c(T,F)), list(yaxis = list(type = 'linear')))),
                          list(label = 'log',
                               method = 'update', 
                               args = list(list(visible = c(F,T)), list(yaxis = list(type = 'log'))))))))
```

The output looks like:
[image]
[image]